# Besides water, which substances are less dense as solids than as liquids?

Tags: phase-transition, density, states-of-matter

You can read everywhere about water's extraordinary property of *expanding* when frozen, thus the reason ice floats on liquid water.

What other substances do this? There are claims of mercury, silica, germanium, bismuth, and antimony, but I've had trouble tracking down the data to back these up.

Comment: Are you asking about specifically elemental substances (all the examples you give except water are elements)? Or any possible compound (in which case giving a list might be a bit broad, could be better to look into *why* water expands when frozen, then figure out what categories/groups of compounds behave similarly).

Comment: Looking to find any possible substance--element or compound. If the list is too great, that in itself would be valuable to know.

Comment: IIRC either liquid 3He or liquid 4He has some similar behavior.

Comment: I also had some trouble getting reliable data, as nowadays there seems to be nothing published about elements anymore. However, "Handbook of physicochemical properties of the elements" (Samsonov, 1968) is _still_ a valued reference for modern physicists, as I found. Antimony is definitely _not_ one of those substances you seek.

Comment: This post (v2) seems like a list question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Density of Solid States of Compounds](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/131687/)

Comment: There is a lot. A quite interesting, also Plutonium is one. I think your question would have more chance to remain open, if you would ask, from what it depends upon.

Answer (score 11):

Wikipedia [quotes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Properties_of_water#Density_of_water_and_ice)

> Other substances that expand on freezing are silicon, gallium, germanium, antimony, bismuth, plutonium and also chemical compounds that form spacious crystal lattices with tetrahedral coordination.

EDIT:The same paragraph says silicon dioxide also exhibits this property.

Comment: Type metal as used by printers is an alloy is antimony, lead and tin has the characteristic of expanding on freezing thus producing sharper type.

Comment: Antimony is _not_ exhibiting such qualities! Uahahahaaha! Wikipedia!!!