# Phase diagram of water v/s other substances

Tags: thermodynamics, water, phase-transition, ice

Why for water increase in pressure decreases solidification temperature?
The fusion curve of water is not same as that of other substances and for other  substances specific volume increases during this period (when they start melting) but not for water (ice) why...?

Comment: This is a duplicate question.  Also, there are at least 4 elements (Si, Ge, Sb, Bi) that have a lower density solid phase at the melting point, so water is not as unusual as you have been led to believe.

Comment: See also http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/131687/26969

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because normal ice, ice Ih, is less dense than liquid water. Ice Ih forms hexagonal crystals. The bonds in that crystalline structure make the water molecules slightly further apart than they are in the liquid form at the same pressure. That water expands on freezing makes water resist freezing as pressure increases. This in turn makes the fusion point decrease with increasing pressure, so long as the pressure isn't so very high that something other than ice Ih results from the freezing process.

There are several other forms of ice besides ice Ih. For example, liquid water freezes to form ice VII instead of ice Ih at extremely high pressures. Ice VII has a cubic crystalline structure rather than than the hexagonal structure of ice Ih. The cubic bonds in ice VII in draw the water molecules closer together in the solid form as opposed to the liquid form. In this extreme high pressure regime, increasing pressure even more raises the fusion temperature. In other words, water behaves like most other substances at very high pressures.

Comment: I was reading the other night that heavy water has a minimum density at 11 C.  (a fun fact.)  The paper was concerned with reducing convective effects in the water.  And operating at the density minimum would help in that regard.

Comment: @GeorgeHerold -- $D_2O$ has a maximum density at 11 C (more precisely, 11.6 °C), not a minimum. Another fun fact: Heavy water ice sinks in ordinary water.