# The Effect of Dissolved Substance to Water Density Anomaly

Tags: water, density

I've read this post [Density of Solid State Compounds](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/131687/228119). As we all know, dissolved substance change water freezing and boiling points. My question is, how a dissolved substance affect the density anomaly?

I also want to know the difference of salt (dissolved but can't be separated using gravity) and clay (dissolved but can be separated with centrifugal) in affecting water density anomaly.

Note: Sorry if clay is not good example, but I know there is a substance that can mix with water but can be separated without distillation.